# Clicking all buttons in <li> tag in loop using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, for-loop

I have a problem. I need to click in all buttons (first is the one I marked, and then to the end of `<li>` tag) in a for loop, using Selenium Python. Every button has a different text and value. How to code it? Could you help me?

```
    <div class="panel panel-default" data-bind=" attr:{'id':'message' + typeId()}" id="message1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isActive, click:$parent.saveIfActiveState">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bind="attr:{'href':'#collapse'+typeId()}" class=""
            href="#collapse1">
            <text data-bind="text:type">Order</text>
            <span class="b-arrow-down pull-right"></span>
          </a>
        </h4>
        <p>Powiadomienie jest wysyłane <text data-bind="text:description">w momencie złożenia zamówienia</text>.</p>
      </div>
      <div data-bind="attr:{'id':'collapse'+typeId()}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse1" style="">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <label>Topic:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value:title" class="messageTitle">
          <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" class="k-widget k-editor k-header k-editor-widget" role="presentation">
            <tbody>
              <tr role="presentation">
                <td class="k-editor-toolbar-wrap" role="presentation">
                  <ul class="k-editor-toolbar" role="toolbar" data-role="editortoolbar">
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start" unselectable="on" title="Wytłuszczenie" aria-pressed="false"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-bold"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wytłuszczenie</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool"
                        unselectable="on" title="Kursywa" aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-italic"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Kursywa</span></a><a href=""
                        role="button" class="k-tool" unselectable="on" title="Podkreślenie" aria-pressed="false"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-underline"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Podkreślenie</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-group-end"
                        unselectable="on" title="Przekreślenie" aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-strikethrough"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Przekreślenie</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start" unselectable="on" title="Wyrównaj tekst do lewej"
                        aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-justifyLeft"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wyrównaj tekst do lewej</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool"
                        unselectable="on" title="Centruj tekst" aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-justifyCenter"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Centruj tekst</span></a><a
                        href="" role="button" class="k-tool" unselectable="on" title="Wyrównaj tekst do prawej"
                        aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-justifyRight"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wyrównaj tekst do prawej</span></a><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-end" unselectable="on" title="Wyrównaj tekst" aria-pressed="false"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-justifyFull"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wyrównaj
                          tekst</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start" unselectable="on" title="Wstaw listę wypunktowaną"
                        aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-insertUnorderedList"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wstaw listę wypunktowaną</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool"
                        unselectable="on" title="Wstaw listę numerowaną" aria-pressed="false"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-insertOrderedList"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wstaw listę
                          numerowaną</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-group-end" unselectable="on"
                        title="Wcięcie"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-indent"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wcięcie</span></a><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-end k-state-disabled" unselectable="on" title="Zmniejsz wcięcie"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-outdent"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Zmniejsz
                          wcięcie</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start k-group-end" unselectable="on" title="Wstaw link"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-createLink"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wstaw
                          link</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-group-end k-state-disabled"
                        unselectable="on" title="Usuń link"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-unlink"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Usuń link</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start k-group-end" data-popup="" unselectable="on"
                        title="Tworzenie tabeli"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-createTable"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Tworzenie tabeli</span></a><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-state-disabled" unselectable="on" title="Wstaw wiersz powyżej"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-addRowAbove"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wstaw wiersz
                          powyżej</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-state-disabled" unselectable="on"
                        title="Wstaw wiersz poniżej"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-addRowBelow"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Wstaw wiersz poniżej</span></a><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-state-disabled" unselectable="on" title="Wstaw kolumnę po lewej"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-addColumnLeft"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wstaw
                          kolumnę po lewej</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-state-disabled"
                        unselectable="on" title="Wstaw kolumnę po prawej"><span unselectable="on"
                          class="k-tool-icon k-addColumnRight"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Wstaw kolumnę po
                          prawej</span></a><a href="" role="button" class="k-tool k-state-disabled" unselectable="on"
                        title="Usuń wiersz"><span unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-deleteRow"></span><span
                          class="k-tool-text">Usuń wiersz</span></a><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-end k-state-disabled" unselectable="on" title="Usuń kolumnę"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-deleteColumn"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Usuń
                          kolumnę</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><span
                        class="k-widget k-combobox k-header k-group-start k-editor-widget" unselectable="on" style=""><span
                          tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><input
                            class="k-input k-fontName k-group-start" type="text" autocomplete="off" title="Wybierz czcionkę"
                            role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"
                            aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="" aria-busy="false" unselectable="on"
                            aria-activedescendant="54e44047-ec3d-4424-8099-2eb94b3bc013" style="width: 100%;"><span
                            tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on"
                              class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button" tabindex="-1">select</span></span></span><select
                          title="Wybierz czcionkę" class="k-fontName k-group-start" data-role="combobox"
                          aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
                          <option value="inherit" unselectable="on">(czcionka odziedziczona)</option>
                          <option value="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" unselectable="on">Arial</option>
                          <option value="'Courier New',Courier,monospace" unselectable="on">Courier New</option>
                          <option value="Georgia,serif" unselectable="on">Georgia</option>
                          <option value="Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif" unselectable="on">Impact</option>
                          <option value="'Lucida Console',Monaco,monospace" unselectable="on">Lucida Console</option>
                          <option value="Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif" unselectable="on">Tahoma</option>
                          <option value="'Times New Roman',Times,serif" unselectable="on">Times New Roman</option>
                          <option value="'Trebuchet MS',Helvetica,sans-serif" unselectable="on">Trebuchet MS</option>
                          <option value="Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" unselectable="on">Verdana</option>
                          <option selected="selected">inherit</option>
                        </select></span><span class="k-widget k-combobox k-header k-editor-widget k-group-end"
                        unselectable="on" style=""><span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on"
                          class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><input class="k-input k-fontSize k-group-end" type="text"
                            autocomplete="off" title="Wybierz rozmiar czcionki" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false"
                            tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns=""
                            aria-busy="false" unselectable="on" aria-activedescendant="29c92454-1062-408f-8f0a-8a5f56de628c"
                            style="width: 100%;"><span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span
                              unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button"
                              tabindex="-1">select</span></span></span><select title="Wybierz rozmiar czcionki"
                          class="k-fontSize k-group-end" data-role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"
                          unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
                          <option value="inherit" unselectable="on">(rozmiar odziedziczony)</option>
                          <option value="xx-small" unselectable="on">1 (8pt)</option>
                          <option value="x-small" unselectable="on">2 (10pt)</option>
                          <option value="small" unselectable="on">3 (12pt)</option>
                          <option value="medium" unselectable="on">4 (14pt)</option>
                          <option value="large" unselectable="on">5 (18pt)</option>
                          <option value="x-large" unselectable="on">6 (24pt)</option>
                          <option value="xx-large" unselectable="on">7 (36pt)</option>
                          <option selected="selected">inherit</option>
                        </select></span></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation">
                      <div class="k-colorpicker k-foreColor k-group-start" data-role="colorpicker" style="display: none;">
                      </div><span role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true"
                        class="k-widget k-colorpicker k-header k-editor-widget" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"
                        aria-label="Current selected color is " title="Kolor" unselectable="on"
                        aria-owns="054e1532-25c1-402c-9428-8eceb8903a49"><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default"
                          unselectable="on"><span class="k-tool-icon k-foreColor" unselectable="on"><span
                              class="k-selected-color" unselectable="on"
                              style="background-color: transparent;"></span></span><span class="k-select"
                            unselectable="on"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"
                              unselectable="on"></span></span></span></span>
                      <div class="k-colorpicker k-backColor" data-role="colorpicker" style="display: none;"></div><span
                        role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true"
                        class="k-widget k-colorpicker k-header k-editor-widget k-group-end" aria-disabled="false"
                        tabindex="0" aria-label="Current selected color is " title="Kolor tła" unselectable="on"
                        aria-owns="f7b0f393-2011-42ea-b482-a3ea3c09f549"><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default"
                          unselectable="on"><span class="k-tool-icon k-backColor" unselectable="on"><span
                              class="k-selected-color" unselectable="on"
                              style="background-color: transparent;"></span></span><span class="k-select"
                            unselectable="on"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"
                              unselectable="on"></span></span></span></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group k-button-group" role="presentation"><a href="" role="button"
                        class="k-tool k-group-start k-group-end" unselectable="on" title="Pokaż HTML"><span
                          unselectable="on" class="k-tool-icon k-viewHtml"></span><span class="k-tool-text">Pokaż
                          HTML</span></a></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[Name]]'});">Name</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[ImieNazwiskoUzytkownika]]'});">Imię
                        i nazwisko użytkownika</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[UwagiUzytkownika]]'});">Uwagi
                        użytkownika</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[StatusZamowienia]]'});">Status
                        zamówienia</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[CalkowityKoszt]]'});">Całkowity
                        koszt</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[WartoscProduktow]]'});">Wartość
                        produktów</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[KosztDostawy]]'});">Koszt
                        dostawy</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[SposobDostawy]]'});">Sposób
                        dostawy</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[DataPlatnosci]]'});">Data
                        płatności</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[SposobPlatnosci]]'});">Sposób
                        płatności</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[StatusPlatnosci]]'});">Status
                        płatności</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[ZamowioneTowary]]'});">Zamówione
                        towary</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[ZamowioneTowaryMini]]'});">Zamówione
                        towary - podstawowe informacje</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[DaneDoWysylki]]'});">Dane do
                        wysyłki</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[DaneDoFaktury]]'});">Dane do
                        faktury</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[ProceduraReklamacyjna]]'});">Link
                        do strony z procedurą reklamacyjną</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[PrawoDoOdstąpieniaOdUmowy]]'});">Link
                        do strony z prawem do odstąpieniem od umowy</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[DaneFirmy]]'});">Dane
                        firmy</button></li>
                    <li class="k-tool-group" role="presentation"><button class="k-button k-group-start k-group-end"
                        onclick="$('#editor_1').data('kendoEditor').exec('inserthtml',{value:'[[LinkDoPlatnosci]]'});">Link
                        do płatności</button></li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="k-editable-area"><iframe title="Editable area. Press F10 for toolbar." frameborder="0"
                    class="k-content" tabindex="0"
                    src="javascript:document.write('<script>document.domain=&quot;feniks.dev.ins.pl&quot;</script>')"></iframe><textarea
                    data-bind="kendoEditor:{value:content,tools:avaliableFields}, attr:{'id':'editor_' + typeId()}"
                    data-role="editor" autocomplete="off" class="k-content k-raw-content" id="editor_1"
                    style="display: none;"></textarea></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div>
            <div class="btn-main pull-right" data-bind="click:$parent.saveTemplate">Zapisz</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It looks like (buttons located above the textarea):

[image: buttons]

I want to click all buttons above the textarea in a one loop. Could you help me?

Comment: can you post link to the html page or post html code as text?

Comment: Ok, I posted code as text (sorry for bad formatting) :/

Comment: Can you post a link to the page and visually describe the buttons you would like to click (and any other values that you would like to extract)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your python code?

Comment: Ok, I added a photo, hope it help! I use a simple ```.click()``` so far, for each buttons.